# is it possible for the phase difference between voltage and current to exceed pi/2 in a RL circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, phasor

I did an experiment where I made a RL circuit. My IV was resistance and DV was phase difference between voltage and current. To find the phase difference, I took the difference (Δt) between time when voltage was maximum and time when current was maximum (I made sure time for Vmax < time for Imax, since voltage leads current in an RL circuit). To get phase difference in radians, I did (Δt/time period)*2pi. I got time period by doing 1/frequency (I used a 50Hz AC generator). But when I did all this, I get phase difference values that exceed pi/2.
Is there anything wrong I did here? If not, how is it possible (in terms of physics) for the phase difference to exceed pi/2?

If it helps, this is how I set up the circuit.
[image]

Sorry if the answer is actually something really simple. I've tried googling but found nothing. Also, please explain in layman's terms!! I'm a high schooler and we've never actually covered inductors in school.

Comment: No. Current always lags 90 deg in an ideal L or less with a series R. With a parallel LC with get 180 deg inversion or less with a series R

Comment: Your schematic shows an ammeter and a voltmeter. Unless you mean something different by "voltmeter" and "ammeter", they are not suitable for measuring the time delay between the peaks of a 50Hz voltage signal and the peaks of your 50Hz current signal? So how did you measure the time difference of the peaks of those two signals?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I connected the voltmeter and ammeter to a data logger and collected time based data points. I set it up so that it would collect 5000 samples per second for a duration of 0.05s.

Comment: How did you synchronize the data collection from the two devices?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy they were connected to the same data logger. voltage and current were measured simultaneously.

Comment: What happens if you connect two voltmeters, each measuring the same signal, to your data logger? Do they report identical results? Or is there a time shift between them? Alternatively, measure the voltage across a resistor, and the current through it, and compare timing.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy hmm I haven't considered that... ill try that out when school reopens. for the second part though, if I measure voltage across the resistor only, wouldn't that be disregarding the effect of the inductor? cuz I've measured the resistance of the inductor and it came out to be 14.6 ohms which is hard to neglect. and with a significant amount of resistance coming from the inductor, voltage measured across both the inductor and resistor VS voltage measured across only the resistor would have a big difference. or is there something I haven't understood? ty for helping!!

Comment: @butterchickencurry. The resistance in the inductor will affect the phase shift. But a simple RL circuit will not have a current-to-voltage phase shift greater than pi/2 radians. If you are getting a result of more than pi/2 radians, there is something wrong with the measurement. The idea of measuring the voltage across and current through a resistor is to see if their phases differ according to the logger. At 50Hz, a resistor should look like a pure resistor, so the phase difference should be 0. If it is other than 0, you need to figure out how to synchronize your data logging.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy ohh I see. so it's somewhat like a pilot testing stage. thank you so so much!!